# Cassandra server/db won't start on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, cassandra, startup

My logs when I run cassandra.bat

C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\bin>cassandra.bat

```
Starting Cassandra Server
 INFO 12:45:45,145 Logging initialized
 INFO 12:45:45,169 Loading settings from file:/C:/Downloads/apache-cassandra-2.0
.9/conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 12:45:45,372 Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO 12:45:45,373 Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
 INFO 12:45:45,373 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode
is mmap
 INFO 12:45:45,373 disk_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 12:45:45,374 commit_failure_policy is stop
 INFO 12:45:45,378 Global memtable threshold is enabled at 256MB
 INFO 12:45:45,461 Not using multi-threaded compaction
 INFO 12:45:45,669 JVM vendor/version: IBM J9 VM/1.7.0
 WARN 12:45:45,669 Non-Oracle JVM detected.  Some features, such as immediate un
map of compacted SSTables, may not work as intended
 INFO 12:45:45,669 Heap size: 1073741824/1073741824
 INFO 12:45:45,670 class storage Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 11851900(1
1574K) committed = 12138540(11854K) max = -1(-1K)
 INFO 12:45:45,670 JIT code cache Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 8388608(8
192K) committed = 8388608(8192K) max = -1(-1K)
 INFO 12:45:45,670 JIT data cache Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 124704(12
1K) committed = 2097152(2048K) max = -1(-1K)
 INFO 12:45:45,672 miscellaneous non-heap storage Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K)
used = 0(0K) committed = 0(0K) max = -1(-1K)
 INFO 12:45:45,672 Java heap Heap memory: init = 1073741824(1048576K) used = 163
447504(159616K) committed = 1073741824(1048576K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
 INFO 12:45:45,672 Classpath: C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\conf;C:\Downlo
ads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\antlr-3.2.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9
\lib\apache-cassandra-2.0.9.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\apache-c
assandra-clientutil-2.0.9.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\apache-cas
sandra-thrift-2.0.9.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\commons-cli-1.1.
jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\commons-codec-1.2.jar;C:\Downloads\a
pache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.
0.9\lib\compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\concurren
tlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\disruptor-3.0
.1.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\guava-15.0.jar;C:\Downloads\apach
e-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0
.9\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\jackso
n-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\jamm-0.2.5.jar;C:
\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\jbcrypt-0.3m.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassa
ndra-2.0.9\lib\jline-1.0.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\json-simple
-1.1.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\libthrift-0.9.1.jar;C:\Download
s\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.
9\lib\lz4-1.2.0.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\metrics-core-2.2.0.j
ar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\netty-3.6.6.Final.jar;C:\Downloads\ap
ache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\reporter-config-2.1.0.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra
-2.0.9\lib\servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.
jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\snakeyaml-1.11.jar;C:\Downloads\apac
he-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\snappy-java-1.0.5.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9
\lib\snaptree-0.1.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\super-csv-2.1.0.ja
r;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\thrift-server-internal-only-0.3.3.jar;
C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\build\classes\main;C:\Downloads\apache-cassa
ndra-2.0.9\build\classes\thrift;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\jamm-0.2
.5.jar;C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\lib\jamm-0.2.5.jar
 INFO 12:45:45,674 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
 INFO 12:45:45,685 Initializing key cache with capacity of 51 MBs.
 INFO 12:45:45,691 Scheduling key cache save to each 14400 seconds (going to sav
e all keys).
 INFO 12:45:45,692 Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs
 INFO 12:45:45,697 Scheduling row cache save to each 0 seconds (going to save al
l keys).
 INFO 12:45:45,919 Initializing system.schema_triggers
 INFO 12:45:45,940 Initializing system.compaction_history
 INFO 12:45:45,947 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\compaction_history\sys
tem-compaction_history-jb-84 (238 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:45,947 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\compaction_history\sys
tem-compaction_history-jb-83 (249 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:45,947 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\compaction_history\sys
tem-compaction_history-jb-81 (5586 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:45,947 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\compaction_history\sys
tem-compaction_history-jb-82 (249 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:45,969 Initializing system.batchlog
 INFO 12:45:45,976 Initializing system.sstable_activity
 INFO 12:45:45,979 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\sstable_activity\syste
m-sstable_activity-jb-154 (125 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:45,979 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\sstable_activity\syste
m-sstable_activity-jb-153 (125 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:45,979 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\sstable_activity\syste
m-sstable_activity-jb-155 (207 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:45,979 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\sstable_activity\syste
m-sstable_activity-jb-156 (210 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:45,985 reading saved cache \var\lib\cassandra\saved_caches\system-ss
table_activity-KeyCache-b.db
 INFO 12:45:45,990 Initializing system.peer_events
 INFO 12:45:45,993 Initializing system.compactions_in_progress
 INFO 12:45:45,997 Initializing system.hints
 INFO 12:45:46,002 Initializing system.schema_keyspaces
 INFO 12:45:46,005 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_keyspaces\syste
m-schema_keyspaces-jb-74 (155 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,005 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_keyspaces\syste
m-schema_keyspaces-jb-75 (155 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,005 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_keyspaces\syste
m-schema_keyspaces-jb-73 (243 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,009 reading saved cache \var\lib\cassandra\saved_caches\system-sc
hema_keyspaces-KeyCache-b.db
 INFO 12:45:46,013 Initializing system.range_xfers
 INFO 12:45:46,018 Initializing system.schema_columnfamilies
 INFO 12:45:46,021 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_columnfamilies\
system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-73 (844 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,021 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_columnfamilies\
system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-71 (5601 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,021 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_columnfamilies\
system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-72 (844 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,025 reading saved cache \var\lib\cassandra\saved_caches\system-sc
hema_columnfamilies-KeyCache-b.db
 INFO 12:45:46,032 Initializing system.NodeIdInfo
 INFO 12:45:46,035 Initializing system.paxos
 INFO 12:45:46,040 Initializing system.schema_columns
 INFO 12:45:46,043 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_columns\system-
schema_columns-jb-73 (249 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,043 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_columns\system-
schema_columns-jb-71 (6436 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,043 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_columns\system-
schema_columns-jb-72 (857 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,047 reading saved cache \var\lib\cassandra\saved_caches\system-sc
hema_columns-KeyCache-b.db
 INFO 12:45:46,052 Initializing system.IndexInfo
 INFO 12:45:46,054 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\IndexInfo\system-Index
Info-jb-1 (80 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,054 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\IndexInfo\system-Index
Info-jb-2 (81 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,059 reading saved cache \var\lib\cassandra\saved_caches\system-In
dexInfo-KeyCache-b.db
 INFO 12:45:46,065 Initializing system.peers
 INFO 12:45:46,066 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\peers\system-peers-jb-
1 (30 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,073 Initializing system.local
 INFO 12:45:46,074 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\local\system-local-jb-
109 (5714 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,077 reading saved cache \var\lib\cassandra\saved_caches\system-lo
cal-KeyCache-b.db
 INFO 12:45:46,534 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-local@1594754130(114/1140 seriali
zed/live bytes, 3 ops)
 INFO 12:45:46,535 Writing Memtable-local@1594754130(114/1140 serialized/live by
tes, 3 ops)
 INFO 12:45:46,566 Completed flushing \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\local\syste
m-local-jb-110-Data.db (139 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segment
Id=1410291946498, position=271)
 INFO 12:45:46,603 Initializing nlh.appconfigproperty
 INFO 12:45:46,606 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\nlh\appconfigproperty\nlh-app
configproperty-jb-1 (103970 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,606 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\nlh\appconfigproperty\nlh-app
configproperty-jb-2 (235 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,612 reading saved cache \var\lib\cassandra\saved_caches\nlh-appco
nfigproperty-KeyCache-b.db
 INFO 12:45:46,622 Initializing nlh.appconfigproperty.propertyvalue_index
 INFO 12:45:46,625 Opening \var\lib\cassandra\data\nlh\appconfigproperty\nlh-app
configproperty.propertyvalue_index-jb-2 (111 bytes)
 INFO 12:45:46,632 Submitting index build of appconfigproperty.propertyvalue_ind
ex for data in SSTableReader(path='\var\lib\cassandra\data\nlh\appconfigproperty
\nlh-appconfigproperty-jb-2-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='\var\lib\cassandra\da
ta\nlh\appconfigproperty\nlh-appconfigproperty-jb-1-Data.db')
 INFO 12:45:46,635 Initializing system_traces.sessions
 INFO 12:45:46,639 Initializing system_traces.events
 INFO 12:45:46,640 completed pre-loading (20 keys) key cache.
 INFO 12:45:46,647 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1410288604
255.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1410289714546.log, \var\lib\ca
ssandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1410290397042.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\Co
mmitLog-3-1407395443659.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
660.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443661.log, \var\lib\ca
ssandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443662.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\Co
mmitLog-3-1407395443663.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
664.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443665.log, \var\lib\ca
ssandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443666.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\Co
mmitLog-3-1407395443667.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
668.log, \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443669.log, \var\lib\ca
ssandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443670.log
 INFO 12:45:46,659 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1410288604
255.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,680 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-appconfigproperty.propertyvalue_i
ndex@-1485203954(6398/135518 serialized/live bytes, 152 ops)
 INFO 12:45:46,681 Writing Memtable-appconfigproperty.propertyvalue_index@-14852
03954(6398/135518 serialized/live bytes, 152 ops)
 INFO 12:45:46,684 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-141
0288604255.log
 INFO 12:45:46,684 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1410289714
546.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,686 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-141
0289714546.log
 INFO 12:45:46,687 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1410290397
042.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,689 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-141
0290397042.log
 INFO 12:45:46,690 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
659.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,717 CFS(Keyspace='nlh', ColumnFamily='appconfigproperty.propertyv
alue_index') liveRatio is 18.652078774617067 (just-counted was 18.65207877461706
7).  calculation took 49ms for 140 cells
ERROR 12:45:46,722 Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:1,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: 135518
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.writeWithShortLength(ByteBu
fferUtil.java:342)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex$Builder.maybeWriteRowHeader(Colum
nIndex.java:201)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex$Builder.add(ColumnIndex.java:188)

        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex$Builder.build(ColumnIndex.java:13
3)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.rawAppend(SSTableWriter
.java:202)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.append(SSTableWriter.ja
va:187)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Me
mtable.java:397)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runWith(Memtable.java:
350)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareR
unnable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:2
8)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1156)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:626)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
 INFO 12:45:46,835 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443659.log
 INFO 12:45:46,836 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
660.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,836 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443660.log
 INFO 12:45:46,837 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
661.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,837 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443661.log
 INFO 12:45:46,838 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
662.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,838 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443662.log
 INFO 12:45:46,839 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
663.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,839 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443663.log
 INFO 12:45:46,840 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
664.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,840 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443664.log
 INFO 12:45:46,841 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
665.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,841 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443665.log
 INFO 12:45:46,841 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
666.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,842 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443666.log
 INFO 12:45:46,842 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
667.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,843 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443667.log
 INFO 12:45:46,843 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
668.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,844 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443668.log
 INFO 12:45:46,844 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
669.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,844 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443669.log
 INFO 12:45:46,845 Replaying \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-1407395443
670.log (CL version 3, messaging version 7)
 INFO 12:45:46,845 Finished reading \var\lib\cassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-3-140
7395443670.log
 INFO 12:45:46,847 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-compactions_in_progress@158274783
8(213/2130 serialized/live bytes, 10 ops)
 INFO 12:45:46,847 Writing Memtable-compactions_in_progress@1582747838(213/2130
serialized/live bytes, 10 ops)
 INFO 12:45:46,847 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-sstable_activity@1201558093(270/2
700 serialized/live bytes, 45 ops)
 INFO 12:45:46,868 Completed flushing \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\compactions
_in_progress\system-compactions_in_progress-jb-1-Data.db (64 bytes) for commitlo
g position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1410291946498, position=271)
 INFO 12:45:46,869 Writing Memtable-sstable_activity@1201558093(270/2700 seriali
zed/live bytes, 45 ops)
 INFO 12:45:46,888 Completed flushing \var\lib\cassandra\data\system\sstable_act
ivity\system-sstable_activity-jb-157-Data.db (221 bytes) for commitlog position
ReplayPosition(segmentId=1410291946498, position=271)
 INFO 12:51:46,868 CFS(Keyspace='system', ColumnFamily='sstable_activity') liveR
atio is 14.044444444444444 (just-counted was 14.044444444444444).  calculation t
ook 0ms for 9 cells
```

When running cqlsh.bat

```
C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\bin>cqlsh
  1 [main] python 15844 C:\rhcygwin\bin\python.exe: *** fatal error - couldn't allocate heap, Win32 error 487, base 0xB00000, top 0xD30000, reserve_size 228
  9664, allocsize 2293760, page_const 4096
  Stack trace:
    Frame     Function  Args
    0028E4EC  6102796B  (0028E4EC, 00000000, 00000000, 00780000)
    0028E7DC  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
    0028F80C  61004F1B  (611B66CC, 00B00000, 00D30000, 0022F000)
    0028F83C  6106E8B3  (7FFEFFFF, 000000FF, 00000008, 76EEFEA2)
    0028F92C  610C132B  (000000D4, 02000000, 6116A724, 6116A720)
    0028F95C  610064C0  (00000000, 76F2217F, 0028F9EC, 00000009)
    0028FA1C  6106FC05  (61000000, 00000001, 0028FD24, 00000001)
    0028FA3C  76F099A0  (6106F950, 61000000, 00000001, 0028FD24)
    0028FB30  76F0D939  (0028FD24, 7EFDD000, 7EFDE000, 76FD206C)
    0028FCB0  76F1686C  (0028FD24, 76ED0000, 61A49545, 00000000)
    0028FD00  76F15326  (0028FD24, 76ED0000, 00000000, 00000000)
    0028FD10  76F09EF9  (0028FD24, 76ED0000, 00000000, 0001002F)
    End of stack trace
   0 [main] python 22416 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
    Connection error: Could not connect to localhost:9160
```

**UPDATE** I downloaded the binary from http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ but the problem still persists. I have tried using version 2.0.9 as well 2.0.10 version but the problem still persists.

I don't have Python installed on my Windows machine.

Comment: It looks like your Cassandra did start, it's cqlsh that crashed. Have you tried to run it with non-cygwin python?

Comment: What steps you did for setting up cassandra?
i am using cassandra in windows 7 only everytime it worked fine only.
have you downloaded cassandra from http://cassandra.apache.org/ their is a chance of problem if cassandra package is not proper.

Comment: I downloaded Cassandra distribution from http://cassandra.apache.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra.yaml comes with Unix style paths for various directories like

```
 INFO 12:45:45,372 Data files directories: [/var/lib/cassandra/data]
 INFO 12:45:45,373 Commit log directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
```

You need to change them to Windows paths for Cassandra to start properly. For e.g.

```
data_file_directories: C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\var\lib\cassandra\data

# commit log
commitlog_directory: C:\Downloads\apache-cassandra-2.0.9\var\lib\cassandra\commitlog
```

Search for all /var/log entries and modify them to valid Windows paths.

Comment: How does that help? The local file system stores the logs at c:\var\lib\cassandra\..